# React - Nodejs / express get request using axios - can't hit my backend route from client - what is the mistake?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, httprequest, nodes

I am trying to make an api request from my backend route (using nodes/express). From the client site, I am making an axios request and using react. I tested my express backend route and it works just fine, so the problem must lay in my client side code. Ive been looking at it for a while now and don't know what I am doing wrong-any help would be great! Thanks!

my backend node express route:

```
 router.get('/testing', function(req,res){
        sampleAPI.get('example/?origin=' + req.query.city + '&name=' + req.query.name + '&xxx=yes&yyy=no&xyx=maybe', function(err, data){
                  if (err){
                     res.status(200).send(err);
                  }
                  else{
                     res.status(200).send(data);
                  }
         })
 })
```

api request:

```
     export function search (city, name) {
            return axios.get('api/testing', {
                params: {
                    city: city,
                    name:name
                }
     })
```

react component:

```
        import React from 'react';
        import {search} from '../api.js';
        class Searching extends React.Component {
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state={
                    city:'',
                    name:''
                }
                this.handleInput=this.handleInput.bind(this);
                this.testing=this.testing.bind(this);
            }
            testing(e){
                this.setState({
                    [e.target.name]:e.target.value
                })
            }

            handleInput(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                search(this.state.city, this.state.name)
            }
            render () {
                return (
                    <div>
                      <form onSubmit={this.handleInput}>
                         <input type="text" name="city"  value={this.state.city} onChange={this.testing} />
                         <input type="text"  name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.testing}/>
                         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                       </form>
                    </div>
                 )
            }
        }

        export default Searching;
```

Comment: Take a look in the Network section of your browser dev tools. Is a request being sent? Does it have the correct parameters? Have you tried sprinkling console logging throughout your client code to confirm that each function is being called with the correct arguments?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Ive just looked into my network section and there is a request being sent but 1) the request doesn't include the entire url: '&xxx=yes&yyy=no&xyx=maybe' is not included, do you have an idea why? It shouldn't be needed to be included in my axios request..

Answer (score 0):

In your axios request you are targeting an endpoint of `'api/testing'`.  The express router route that you are targeting is `'/testing'`, so somewhere in that router file you are nesting that `'/testing'` endpoint within the '/api' route like `router.use('/api', require('./api'));` ?

Does this axios request work:

```
export function search (city, name) {
   return axios.get(`/api/testing/${city}/${name}`);
}
```

With this endpoint:

```
router.get('/testing/:city/:name', function(req,res){
    sampleAPI.get('example/?origin=' + req.params.city + '&name=' + req.params.name + '&xxx=yes&yyy=no&xyx=maybe', function(err, data){
        if (err){
           res.status(200).send(err);
        }
        else {
           res.status(200).send(data);
        }
     })
}
```